# Change date labels when plotting pandas series with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a time series of monthly data like this, and plot it like this:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1965-01-01', periods=600, freq='M')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ts.plot(ax=ax)
```

The major tick marks are set every 10 years, beginning in 1969. I'd like to change this so they start in 1975. After looking at some matplotlib samples ([here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html) and [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo2.html)) I tried adding

```
from matplotlib.dates import YearLocator, DateFormatter
decs = YearLocator(10)   # decades
decsFmt = DateFormatter("%Y")

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(decs)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(decsFmt)

datemin = pd.datetime(ts.index.min().year, 1, 1)
datemax = pd.date(ts.index.max().year + 1, 1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(datemin, datemax)
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use matplotlib to set axis limits you will need to turn off pandas' date formatting.

Just change the line to

```
ts.plot(x_compat=True, ax=ax)
```

and it should work.